# How to plot multiple factor columns with ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to plot multiple factor columns in one go, using ggplot2 as plotting engine.

Plotting multiple *metric* columns is straight forward:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr) # dplyr 0.5.0 select_if
library(purrr)
data(diamonds)


diamonds %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  facet_wrap(~key)
```

[image: plot multiple quantitative variables]

However, I did not success in plotting multiple *factor* (qualitative) columns in one shot. I would like to choose columns programmatically, ie., *not* directly naming them.

I tried this, but it does *not* produce a sensible result:

```
diamonds %>% 
  select_if(is.factor) %>% 
  gather %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) + geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~key) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

I assume that there might a solution along these lines:

```
diamonds %>% 
  select_if(is.factor) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = .[[1]])) + geom_bar()
```

Where `.[[1]]` should be replaced by some column placeholder (so here I directly named the column, which I would like to avoid, as I have a large number of columns in reality).

A for-loop will probably do the job, but I would like to get there with dplyr.

Comment: Could you explain what you would consider a sensible result, i.e. how your second figure differs from your desired output? Is the main problem the the fact that each plot doesn't have its own Y-axis (and therefore the alphabetical sorting is pretty meaningless)?

Comment: #mkt, thanks for your comment, #Axeman had a good idea, that was what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is to use `scales = free` within your `facet` call. For example:

```
diamonds %>% 
    select_if(is.factor) %>% 
    gather %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = value)) + geom_bar() +
    facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free') +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Unfortunately free scales and `coord_flip` don't play nice. You can either use `geom_barh` from [the `ggstance` package](https://github.com/lionel-/ggstance). Or you can use `lapply` on each column to get a list of `ggplot` objects and use the `cowplot` package to stitch them together in one figure.

Comment: It just came to my mind that `lapply` might also be a way, maybe easier to play together with `coord_flip`@Axeman

Answer (score 1):

Maybe less elegant than @Axeman, but also working, and cooperates with `coord_flip`:

```
library(gridExtra)


gg_bar <- function(x, ...){
  { 
    ggplot(data_frame(x), aes(x = x)) + 
      geom_bar() +
      coord_flip() 
  }
}

diamonds %>% 
  select_if(negate(is.numeric)) %>% 
  lapply(., function(x) gg_bar(x)) -> gg_bar_list

do.call(grid.arrange, gg_bar_list)
```

[image]

However, the name of the variable ("x") is not shown, that's not too beautiful.

Comment: See [`cowplot::plot_grid`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html) instead of `grid.arrange` to do automatic alignment and subplot annotation. You can use the annotations as variable labels, and not show the y-axis label.